# my sql update doesnt commit

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to run the below code

```
update apidura_dwh.B2C_order_line
join apidura_dwh.B2C_orders
using (order_id)
set apidura_dwh.B2C_order_line.order_date = apidura_dwh.B2C_orders.order_date;
commit;
```

basically just wanting to add the order date to the line table - this returns a successful message and says that rows have been changed - however when i query the order line table no rows are changed.

[image]

it does appear to work if i join on the orders table

[image]

- any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What SQL client are you using? Does it have a Commit button?

Comment: I would avoid using the using clause in joins unless you are 100% sure (and why rely on that) that there is only 1 column in each table that mysql can use.

Answer (score 0):

This would suggest that you have either non-matching orders or orders with `NULL` dates.  First, I would write the query as:

```
update apidura_dwh.B2C_order_line ol join
       apidura_dwh.B2C_orders o
       using (order_id)
    set ol.order_date = o.order_date;
commit;
```

To test if the update works -- and assuming that `ol.order_id` is `NULL` -- then you can do:

```
select count(*)
from apidura_dwh.B2C_order_line ol
where ol.order_date is null;
```

Both before and after the update.

You can look for missing order ids by doing:

```
select count(*)
from apidura_dwh.B2C_order_line ol left join
     apidura_dwh.B2C_orders o
     using (order_id)
where o.order_id is null;
```

And for `NULL` dates using:

```
select count(*)
from apidura_dwh.B2C_orders o
where o.order_date is null;
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer - I found no orders with missing dates or order id (in the B2C orders table) - the issue is in the order line table which i cannot populate the order_date column with an update. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JOIN inside a UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE B2C_order_line
SET B2C_order_line.order_date = B2C_orders.order_date
FROM B2C_orders
WHERE
B2C_order_line.order_id = B2C_orders.order_id;
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it gave me an error - I made the below changes
UPDATE B2C_order_line
SET B2C_order_line.order_date = (select B2C_orders.order_date
FROM B2C_orders
WHERE
B2C_order_line.order_id = B2C_orders.order_id);
however this just had the same problem